# Tableau convert measure to dimension

Tags: plot, tableau-api

I am trying to emulate the [normal bell curve in tableau](https://public.tableau.com/s/blog/2013/11/fitting-normal-curve-histogram)

Created all the variables, and they are proper. But `Rating Bin` [in my workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/BellCurveBusinessRating/Histogram) is not Dimension like `Profit Bin` in [other workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/rkennedy#!/vizhome/Gaussiancurve/Gaussiancurvefitting), and that is making it difficult to plot

```
Curve vs Rating Bin
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I just wanted to create normal distribution  curve from location average ratings

[image]

#### Update

Unable to drag `Rating Bin` from Measures to Dimensions

[image]

#### Update 2

These are options when I right-click

[image]

Comment: You should be able to drag the Rating Bin out of the Measures pane and drop it into the DImensions pane, and then Tableau will treat it as a dimension.  (This will not work if your data source is an OLAP cube.)

Comment: @Hellion I am unable to drag from Measures to Dimensions. I tried converting to continuous. And when I attempt to drag, it shows `ATTR(Rating Bin), but I am unable to drop. I updated original question

Comment: @Hellion Data source is Excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Tableau you are using, but in my version, I can right click on the variable and select "Convert to dimension" from the pop up menu. You should be able to do this, if not drag the field from measure to dimension.

Comment: I am using Tableau Public (to replicate work-sensitive data done on Tableau Desktop 9)

Comment: Is there no right click functionality in that? If not, there should atleast be small arrow button on the variable.

Comment: I don't get option `Convert to dimension`. If I click `Convert to Continuous` then I get option `Convert to Discrete`. I posted screenshot on original question.

Comment: These options seem different to me. Is there any way you can change it if you click on edit?